# Measure Data Transfer for Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I would like to measure the amount of data transferred in and out of Azure Redis Cache.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: This is too vague.  There are a [lot of metrics in Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-monitor/), in the page you use to manage/create Redis caches. Are you looking for something that isn't included there?

Comment: I can see 'Cache Read' and 'Cache Write' metrics but (a) I can't see how to get a total over a week and (b) this seems to be in mb/s which doesn't help.  What I'd like to know is how much 'Data Transfer' I'm being charged for by Microsoft, that is attributed to a Redis Cache instance.